# docker-compose does not run in gitlab CICD after pull image

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I have a project and I use `redis` in this project.

This is my `.gitlab-cu.yml`

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" "$CI_REGISTRY"
    - docker build --pull -t "$DOCKER_IMAGE" .
    - docker push "$DOCKER_IMAGE"

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  services:
    - redis:latest
  script:
    - ssh $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY $USER_NAME@$HOST_NAME docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - ssh $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY $USER_NAME@$HOST_NAME
      docker run --name=$CI_PROJECT_NAME --restart=always --network="host" -v "/app/storage:/src/storage" -d $DOCKER_IMAGE
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY $USER_NAME@$HOST_NAME docker compose up
```

And this my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data/
    command: --port 6379
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    expose:
      - "6379"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
volumes:
  redisdata:
```

everything is OK, but last line not work for me:

```
- ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY $USER_NAME@$HOST_NAME docker compose up
```

So, my redis image not running in this container

Note: I want 1 container with 2 images contains my project and redis

My redis image not running

So, my redis image not running in this container

Note: I want 1 container with 2 images contains my project and redis